# How to read value from root key in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-config

I'm trying to read the application configuration from rootKey but I'm getting null.

```
rootKey1:
   childKey1: childValue1
   childKey2: childValue2
   childKey3: childValue3

rootKey2:
   childKey1: childValue1
   childKey2: childValue2
   childKey3: childValue3
```

```
Environment environment;
getProperty(String key) {
   environment.getProperty(key+".childKey1"); --> is giving childValue1
-------------------
   environment.getProperty(key); --> is giving null
}
```

**Correction:** The rootKey is dynamic.

Comment: What is the configuration file name? What is the path of this file within project?

Comment: Did you @autowired Environment varable?

Comment: Is it totally normal, spring can't find a key called `rootKey`, because it doesn't exist on it's own. If you want to achieve what you are looking for you can create a `ConfigurationProperties` bean

Comment: @Steephen - application.yml under src/main/resources.

Answer (score 1):

Try to define your property object structure and register an appropriate bean.

[Configure a Custom DataSource](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-configure-a-datasource)

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication implements ApplicationRunner {

    @Data
    public static class RootProperty {

        private List<ChildProperty> list;
    }

    @Data
    public static class ChildProperty {

        private String name;
        private String childKey1;
        private String childKey2;
        private String childKey3;
    }

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext context;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties("root-key")
    public RootProperty rootProperty() {
        return new RootProperty();
    }

    @Override
    public void run(ApplicationArguments args) {
        System.out.println(context.getBean("rootProperty"));
    }
}
```

application.yml

```
root-key:
  list:
    - name: child-key1
      childKey1: childValue1-1
      childKey2: childValue1-2
      childKey3: childValue1-3
    - name: child-key2
      childKey1: childValue2-1
      childKey2: childValue2-2
      childKey3: childValue2-3
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. In my use case the number of rootKeys are not constant. I'll be adding additional keys and configuration but I can't keep adding the new methods for each configuration.

Comment: @Prasad it's not a problem. I've updated the answer to support the number of property objects. I suppose it's exactly what you expect.

Comment: This was helpful I'm trying to apply this solution in my other question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64610099/load-multiple-yaml-file-with-same-root-key-in-spring-boot?noredirect=1#comment114269513_64610099

Answer (score 0):

Springboot by default read the configuration file `application.yml` from `/src/main/resources` file path:

DemoApplication.java

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;


    @SpringBootApplication
    public class DemoApplication {
    
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
            
        }
    
    }
```

TestService.java

```
package com.example.demo.service;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class TestService {
    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        System.out.println(env.getProperty("rootKey1.childKey1"));
        System.out.println(env.getProperty("rootKey2.childKey1"));
    }
}
```

Application.yml

```
rootKey1:
   childKey1: childValue1
   childKey2: childValue2
   childKey3: childValue3

rootKey2:
   childKey1: childValue1
   childKey2: childValue2
   childKey3: childValue3
```

Result:

```
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.3.5.RELEASE)

2020-11-01 16:20:04.514  INFO 15400 --- [           main] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : Starting DemoApplication on LAPTOP-TN3LBPJ2 with PID 15400 (C:\code\java\demo\target\classes started by steep in C:\code\java\demo)
2020-11-01 16:20:04.516  INFO 15400 --- [           main] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2020-11-01 16:20:05.576  INFO 15400 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2020-11-01 16:20:05.590  INFO 15400 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2020-11-01 16:20:05.590  INFO 15400 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.39]
2020-11-01 16:20:05.669  INFO 15400 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2020-11-01 16:20:05.669  INFO 15400 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1102 ms

childValue1

childValue1
```